# React-navigation: How to disable swipe on TabNavigator once init?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I set up a [TabNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab) like so :

```
class RNNavigation extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
      ProfileStack: { screen: ProfileStack },
      Home: { screen: Home },
      HistoryStack: { screen: HistoryStack }
    }, {
      initialRouteName: 'Home',
      tabBarComponent: () => { return null; },
      swipeEnabled: true
    });

    return (
      <MainScreenNavigator/>
    );
  }
}
```

At some point I need to disable swipe from a screen component. How to do so? Is it possible without re-rendering the navigator.

------ 15/03/2017 EDIT

Tried passing a callback function through screenProps (only work with beta 7) .. but as expected it goes back to initialRouteName 'Home' when I do it from History since it's re-render.

Same problem with redux ...

Any suggestion is more than welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can turn it into a variable and create a function to toggle it on/off.

```
this.state ={ swipe: true } //set state in constructor
....
toggleSwipe = () => { //function that will be passed down to toggle on/off 
  this.setState((prevState) => ({ swipe: !prevState.swipe });
}
....
swipeEnabled: this.state.swipe //this will now get toggled between true/false
```

Comment: Yes, but how to access the function toggleSwipe inside a screen component? I tried using screenProps but for some reason nothing is rendered when i write  < MainScreenNavigator screenProps={} />

Comment: i dont think anything is supposed to be rendered when you do `< MainScreenNavigator screenProps={} />`, you're just passing down this.props.screenProps to all you tab components.

Comment: What I mean is that add screenProps={...} like doc says make the whole app not rendered. Another problem but my idea was to pass the ref to the toggleSwipe frome there. What's your idea to access the function toggleSwipe inside a screen component?

Comment: So it make a blank screen when you add screenProps there? What do you put inside of it?

Comment: an object, a string, a number, same effect. I might misunderstood something here :)

Comment: Sorry, I havent used this navigation before. Docs are confusing but they say it should work if you put `<MainScreenNavigator screenProps={{ toggleSwipe: this.toggleSwipe }} />`. But doing that makes it go blank?

Comment: yes it does.. once i found the reason why, your solution works for sure.. thanks